# Line below delete button on UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have this problem when I edit my table: a white line appear below the delete button. Any suggestions?

Here is my screen shot:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like wrong content size, have you set up the button's content size manually?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't change the button's content. I am looking change the button heigth in layoutSubviews for solve this problem

Comment: Have you checked if your cell height has the same size as your content? maybe the cell is a bit smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes and is the same. I tried to change the delete button with a custom but when i looping the cell subviews, the king of class of his subviews are UITableViewCellScroll therefore never find UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl type.

Comment: That might be the tableView separator. Are you sure that tableView's separtor is set to None?

Comment: Yes i'm sure.I solve it by reducing the size of the image at 0.5 px and by adding a line with a 0.5 px high and 500 wide. Thanks for helping me!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the button size, or button content 
increase the button height or image.

Comment: I add a view with a 1px height. This solve the problem. Thanks for your answer!